# Special Relativity - Transformation from scalar to 4-vector

Tags: special-relativity, vectors

I'm studying Leonard Susskind's lectures on special relativity. In [lecture 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8ace3NbXAA), when he talks about transformations between scalars and vectors(which is around 1:10:00), he mentions that, to turn a scalar into a vector, you must differentiate the scalar's function with respect to the 4 spacetime dimensions...

My question is: 
When the referred differentiation is mentioned, does he mean to take the gradient of the scalar's function? Because that's what comes to my mind.

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: Yes, if $\phi$ is a scalar, the quantity $\partial_\mu \phi$ is a 4-vector that is the four-dimensional version of the gradient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be sure, the [four-gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient) of a scalar field yields a (covariant) four-vector field

$$\mathbf{\tilde d} \phi(x^\mu) = \partial_\mu\phi\, \tilde\omega^\mu = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}\tilde\omega^\mu =  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^0}\tilde\omega^0 + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^1}\tilde\omega^1+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^2}\tilde\omega^2+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^3}\tilde\omega^3$$

where the $\tilde\omega^\mu$ are the one-form basis for the coordinates $x^\mu$.

That is to say, $\partial_\mu\phi$ are the *components* of a four-vector.